# Operator does not exist: text + integer [Postgres 9.5]

Tags: postgresql-9.5

i have an issue with this piece of code coming from SQL :

```
UPDATE resultats_du_jour
SET Heure_debut =  CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Heure_debut,1,2) +
    12,SUBSTRING(Heure_debut,3,3))
WHERE Heure_debut LIKE '%PM';
```

This gives me the following output :

```
sql:53: ER ROR: operator does not exist: text + integer LINE 1: ...ET Heure_debut = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Heure_debut,1,2)+12,SUBSTR...
```

I understand that you cannot add text+integer, but how can i proceed to do that?

Many thanks.

Comment: Having do update parts of a column value smells like a bad design. Given the name of the column (if my french serves me well), this looks like you are misusing a `text` column to store something like a `time` or an interval. If that was a `time` column, simply adding 12 hours would be as simple as `heure_debut + interval '12 hour'` - or it might not be necessary at all given your condition `like '%PM'` which sounds as if you are fixing a bad user input that could not have happened if you had chosen the correct data type

Comment: In fact, data from csv file come from a format like "03:40 PM" so if we could have use TIME datatype, we would have do it.

Your french serves you well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add 12 to the numerical equivalent of the first substring you take, and then concatenate it again back to text, then you may use casts:

```
UPDATE resultats_du_jour
SET Heure_debut =  CONCAT((SUBSTRING(Heure_debut, 1, 2)::int + 12)::text,
    SUBSTRING(Heure_debut, 3, 3))
WHERE Heure_debut LIKE '%PM';
```

This feels a bit hackish, and in general as a matter of good design you should decide whether a certain type of data is text or a number.  Here, if you had things stored as numbers, you might not need to cast at all.